# The command line statement php artisan tinker isn't working

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I am using laravel 5.1 and I am following a tutorial that I've followed before without any issues. But today when I ran

```
 php artisan tinker
```

I got the following error

```
 PsySH history file found at '/home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history'. Please delete it or move it to '/home/vagrant/.config/psysh/psysh_history'.
```

I have never seen this before and I have been looking for it but dont know where to locate it so  can either delete it or remove it. Also another question I have is should I delete it or move it? I don't want to do something that inadvertantly crashes my app. Thanks in advance

Comment: From the commad line: `rm /home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history`  You probably can't see the file because the `.config` folder is a hidden folder.  You can use the see all of the hidden folders in your vagrant folder with `ls -al /home/vagrant`

Comment: @Parris Varney thanks for the response. Will removing tht cause anything to crash. Do you know what that is exactly?

Comment: It looks like it's a history file for your php debugger, which is likely going to be recreated by your php command.  You can move it `mv /home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history /home/vagrant/.config/psysh/psysh_history`, and move it back if needed, and you can also take a look at what's in it with `head /home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history` if you're concerned.

Comment: @ParrisVarney. I would have upvoted you if I could

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you don't have to answer and accept your own question:

It looks like pshsy_history is a history file for the php debugger psysh, and your php command wants it in a different location from where it is.  I'm guessing it was created the first time you followed the tutorial.

I'm thinking it's safe to delete with `rm /home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history` since your php command seems like it's going to create a new one.

If you want to be on the safe side then to move it like the error message says with `mv /home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history /home/vagrant/.config/psysh/psysh_history`

If you want to double check the contents of the file before doing either, try `head /home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history`.

Comment: This is the file which stores your `tinker` input history. It's automatically generated when you use `tinker`, and exists so that you can use the `hist` command to view, search and replay history. There was a bug in the last version which put it in the wrong place, and the error message you see is prompting you to either remove the file entirely, or put it where it goes. It's perfectly safe to delete; all it will do is remove whatever command history you have from previous `tinker` sessions.

Comment: I have solved this problem like the procedure you mentioned but the problem is why the history remains after using tinker?

Answer (score 1):

find "psysh_history" manually in "home" folder and than move or remove file

Note: Its a hidden file

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers:

I had a similar issue today. The only difference was I was not running my project on vagrant instead of MAMP.

Few different things I had to do besides what are mentioned above were :

Moved the folder  `../.config/psysh/psysh_history` and did following :

1) **I had to shut down the MAMP**

2) **Restart terminal**

3) `php artisan tinker`

Note: I was not able to run `tinker` until I restarted MAMP and terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue but

**I didn't find psysh_history file in .config folder**.
But because it was asking to move the psysh_history file to .config/psysh, so I just created a folder psysh inside .config folder and it works.